# Manually set color of points in legend

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colors, legend

I'm making a scatter plot which looks like this:

[image]

(MWE at bottom of question)

As can be seen in the image above the colors of the points in the legend are set to blue automatically by `matplotlib`. I need to set this points to some other color not present in the colormap (ie: black) so they won't generate confusion with the colors associated with said colormap.

I looked around but the [matplotlib.legend](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html) module does not seem to accept a `color` keyword. Is there any way to do this?

---

Here's the MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def rand_data():
    return np.random.uniform(low=0., high=1., size=(100,))

# Generate data.
x, y, x2, x3 = [rand_data() for i in range(4)]
# This data defines the markes and labels used.
x1 = np.random.random_integers(7, 9, size=(100,))

# Order all lists so smaller points are on top.
order = np.argsort(-np.array(x2))
# Order x and y.
x_o, y_o = np.take(x, order), np.take(y, order)
# Order list related to markers and labels.
z1 = np.take(x1, order)
# Order list related to sizes.
z2 = np.take(x2, order)
# Order list related to colors.
z3 = np.take(x3, order)

plt.figure()
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')

# Scatter plot where each value in z1 has a different marker and label
# assigned.
mrk = {7: ('o', '7'), 8: ('s', '8'), 9: ('D', '9')}
for key, value in mrk.items():

    s1 = (z1 == key)
    plt.scatter(x_o[s1], y_o[s1], marker=value[0], label=value[1],
        s=z2[s1] * 100., c=z3[s1], cmap=cm, lw=0.2)

# Plot colorbar
plt.colorbar()

# Plot legend.
plt.legend(loc="lower left", markerscale=0.7, scatterpoints=1, fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can obtain the legend handles and change their colors individually:

```
ax = plt.gca()
leg = ax.get_legend()
leg.legendHandles[0].set_color('red')
leg.legendHandles[1].set_color('yellow')
```

Comment: Note that the `legendHandles` attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.7 (and removed in 3.9). It is now called `legend_handles` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to the other answers – I've had trouble in the past changing color of legend markers with `set_color`. An alternate approach is to build the legend yourself:

```
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

eight = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue', marker='s', ls='', label='8')
nine = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue', marker='D', ls='', label='9')
# etc etc
plt.legend(handles=[eight, nine])
```

Building legends from scratch can sometimes save the hassle of dealing with the obscure internals of an already built legend. More information in Matplotlib docs [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html).

Comment: The "ax.get_legend()" method did not work for me (maybe because I was setting the colour of the points based on a condition). Building my own legend worked like a charm. Leaving this comment here so that others in a similar situation may find it useful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the label of each legend handle with `lh.get_label()` if you want to map colors to specific labels.

For my purposes it worked best to create a dict from `legendHandles`  and change the colors like so:

```
ax = plt.gca()
leg = ax.get_legend()
hl_dict = {handle.get_label(): handle for handle in leg.legendHandles}
hl_dict['9'].set_color('red')
hl_dict['8'].set_color('yellow')
```

Answer (score 1):

While I found that the solution with `legendHandles[i].set_color` did not work for `errorbar`, I managed to do the following workaround:

```py
ax_legend = fig.add_subplot(g[3, 0])
ax_legend.axis('off')
handles_markers = []
markers_labels = []
for marker_name, marker_style in markers_style.items():
    pts = plt.scatter([0], [0], marker=marker_style, c='black', label=marker_name)
    handles_markers.append(pts)
    markers_labels.append(marker_name)
    pts.remove()
ax_legend.legend(handles_markers, markers_labels, loc='center', ncol=len(markers_labels), handlelength=1.5, handletextpad=.1)
```

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8807) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the answer of @Saullo G. P. Castro :

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The **legendHandles attribute was
> deprecated** in **Matplotlib 3.7** and will be removed two minor releases
> later. Use legend_handles instead.

---

Future usage:

```
ax = plt.gca()
leg = ax.get_legend()
leg.legend_handles[0].set_color('red')
leg.legend_handles[1].set_color('yellow')
```