# Manually change color in legend of pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having a problem very similar to this one:

[Manually set color of points in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698850/manually-set-color-of-points-in-legend)

Namely, I want to manually change the color of the markers that are displayed in the legend. The only difference to the above linked example is, I use `plt.plot` (no line visible, just the data points) instead of `plt.scatter`. 
The suggested solution was:

```
ax = plt.gca()
leg = ax.get_legend()
leg.legendHandles[0].set_color('yellow')
leg.legendHandles[1].set_color('black')
```

This, however, doesn't do it for me, since the symbols don't seem to be considered part of the line, I guess. `set_markeredgecolor` and `set_markerfacecolor` don't do anything either, and since `set_marker` just adds additional markers in the legend, I assume that the symbols aren't considered as markers as well. None of the above (safe from `set_marker`) raise an error or a warning, they just don't do anything.

Say my code was:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.random(10)
y1 = np.random.random(10)
x2 = np.random.random(10)
y2 = np.random.random(10)

symbolsdic = {0: 'o', 1: '^', 2: 's', 3: '*', 4: 'D', 5: '+', 6: '8', 7: 'd', 8: 'H', 9: 'v'}

for i in range(10):
    plt.plot(x1[i], y1[i], symbolsdic[i], label=str(i), color='red')
    plt.plot(x2[i], y2[i], symbolsdic[i], color='blue')    

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Now I want the symbols in the legend to be all black. What do I do?

Comment: Could you post a minimal, but complete example that can be executed by others. This would help debugging the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the legend handles (i.e. the artists shown in the legend) **are** in fact the points in the plot. Therefore changing their color is reverted in the moment the complete plot is drawn.

You can circumvent this by using a copy of the original artist to put into the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import copy

x1 = np.random.random(10)
y1 = np.random.random(10)
x2 = np.random.random(10)
y2 = np.random.random(10)

symbolsdic = {0: 'o', 1: '^', 2: 's', 3: '*', 4: 'D', 5: '+', 6: '8', 7: 'd', 8: 'H', 9: 'v'}

handles = []
for i in range(10):
    h, = plt.plot(x1[i], y1[i], symbolsdic[i], label=str(i), color='red')
    plt.plot(x2[i], y2[i], symbolsdic[i], color='blue') 
    handles.append(copy.copy(h))


for h in handles:
    h.set_color("gold")

leg = plt.legend(handles=handles)
plt.show()
```

[image]