# Add labels to wireframe plot with facecolor not edgecolor

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following is a working, slightly modified, minimal example from the [matplotlib documentation for wireframe](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/wire3d.html).

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Grab some test data.
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)

# Plot a basic wireframe.
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10,color='black',facecolors='green',label='abc')

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

**My problem is, the legend is black, it should be green.**

How do I change that?

If it is not possible, how do I fake it? Can I do something like `plot(nothing,color='green',legend='abc')`?

Comment: @DizietAsahi that doesn't solve it because wireframe doesn't return a "line" which could then be used for the legend. I found this though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698850/manually-set-color-of-points-in-legend

Comment: The answers to the link question demonstrate how to use a "proxy" artist, i.e. a plot with no data to generate whatever legend you want

Comment: see also the official documentation here https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists

Comment: @DizietAsahi oh thanks, thats great too!